# Incorrect string value when adding a record to a db

Tags: mysql, utf-8, sqlalchemy

I am trying to right the following dictionary to the database:

```
{'genres': 'Horror', 'description': u'Vampire Count Orlok is interested in a new residence and in his real estate agent\u2019s young wife. F.\u202fW. Murnau\u2019s unauthorized adaptation of Bram Stoker\u2019s \u201cDracula.\u201d', 'year': u'1922-03-15', 'id': 653, 'title': 'Nosferatu (Nosferatu, eine Symphonie des Grauens) (1922)'}
```

But I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1366, u"Incorrect string value: '\\xE2\\x80\\xAFW. ...' for column 'description' at row 1") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO movies (id, title, description, year) VALUES (%(id)s, %(title)s, %(description)s, %(year)s)'] [parameters: {'id': 653, 'title': 'Nosferatu (Nosferatu, eine Symphonie des Grauens) (1922)', 'description': u'Vampire Count Orlok is interested in a new residence and in his real estate agent\u2019s young wife. F.\u202fW. Murnau\u2019s unauthorized adaptation of Bram Stoker\u2019s \u201cDracula.\u201d', 'year': u'1922-03-15'}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)
```

engine_connection arguments are:

```
engine = create_engine(url, connect_args={'charset':'utf8mb4'})
```

but still nothing. How do I bypass it?

Code is plain requests usage:

```
//movie is a dictionary containing the id of the movie and the title.
//TMDB is used to download additional info like the overview and release_year, and I update the initial dictionary. Some movie ids were able to store in db.

url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{}?api_key={}'.format(
       movie['id'], api_key)

req = requests.get(url, data={})
resp = req.json()
movie['description'] = resp.get('overview')

movie['year'] = resp.get('release_date')
```

Comment: Hint: That dictionary is not JSON formatted. Are you properly JSON encoding before adding to the database? That code is not shown.

Comment: It seems to be incorrect string encoding problem.

Comment: A JSON string should not include `u'`, nor `\u2019`.  Those are artifacts of the source language's handling of Unicode.